# arithmetic operations in Vuejs Computed

Tags: vue.js

it turns out that I want to perform some operations, but as much as I try I get errors, I hope they can help me.
they wanted to perform some operations with 4 inputs

Example

these conditions must be met

```
         `Input 1     Input 2     Input 3    Input 4

               1) input3 = input1 / input 2
                   2) input2 = input1 * input 3
                       3) input2 = input 4`
```

currently is what I have

```
calcularPrecio: function(){
                var result=0.0;
                
                for(var i=0;i<this.arrayDetalle.length;i++){
                 result=result(this.arrayDetalle[i].precio*this.arrayDetalle[i].cantidad1)
                }
                return result;
            },
```

```
<input type="number"  v-model="calcularPrecio"  class="form-control">

<input v-model="detalle.cantidad1" type="number" class="form-control">
```

I hope you could help me with an example of how I could do it. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you trying to check if the value of Input1/Input2 equals to Input3? Can you please provide javascript code that you are using!

Comment: what I require is that the values ​​are dependent

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `input2` is dependent on `input4` and `input1 * input3`, if you're looking to use computed functions. Unless you want the input returned separately, for which `input2` would be two different computed properties.

Comment: yes exactly that's what I require 2 functions for input 2

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with simple functions:

```
methods: {

   calcA: function () {
       this.inputC = this.inputA / this.inputB

   },
   calcBA: function () {
       this.inputB = this.inputA * this.inputC

   },
   calcBB: function () {
       this.inputB = this.inputD

   },
}
```

or you could use computed properties:

```
computed: {
   outputA: function () {
       return this.inputA / this.inputB

   },
   outputB: function () {
       return this.inputA * this.inputC

   },
   outputC: function () {
       return this.inputD

   },
}
```

You could also use params for the methods, if that's what you want.

There's a 3rd option where you use watchers to watch `input4` for example. On change, update `input2`.

Comment: and the result of the outputs as the subjects to the inputs?